# Change the order of two equal elements in an STL multiset

Tags: c++, stl, set

In C++, I have an STL `multiset<int, cmp>`. I defined a custom compare operator, so two different integers can still compare equal. Given such a case, how can I change the internal order of two integers in the set when they are equal?

I read about the option of adding a second value to the multiset and set its value accordingly to my desired order, however, that seems to be rather complicated. Is there an easier solution, e.g. erasing and inserting the two elements in a specific order?

Comment: A `set` only takes unique elements. If you insert `1` and `2` and `cmp` says they are equal then `2` will not be inserted. Maybe you are looking for `multi_set`?

Comment: Internal order of what? You can't have two equal elements in a set.

Comment: Yes, you are right. A multiset is what I mean, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to re-order the elements is to remove one and re-insert it.

When inserting equal elements into a multiset the added elements will go after existing ones, or you can use the `insert` functions that take a hint, to control where the element is re-inserted.